# Is there a single cron expression to run hourly on both partial and full days?

Tags: command-line

I want a cron job to run at minute 55 that starts at 5pm on Sunday, keeps going all day Monday, and stops at 12pm on Tuesday.

Currently, I simply have 3 crontab entries running the same command to cover each day's range, but I'm curious if there's a single expression that does it all.

I assume there's not, but I'm not an expert.

Here are the 3 cron expressions I'm currently using, and I'd like to know if there's a way to do exactly this in one expression:

```
# Every minute 55 from 5pm to midnight on Sundays
0 55 17-23 * * 7 *
# Every minute 55 all of Monday, every Monday
0 55 * * * 1 *
# Every minute 55 from midnight to 12pm on Tuesdays
0 55 0-11 * * 2 *
```

By the way, I'm using the cron-plus node in Node-RED to do this on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Can you include the time portion of the 3 crontab entries you are currently using?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I will add them in a little bit

Comment: What's with the leading zero? The first field is for minutes, no?

Comment: Seconds. Note, **I'm using the cron-plus node in Node-RED to do this on a Raspberry Pi.** It includes seconds as the first value in the expression.

Comment: And it works as I described in the comments above each expression.  I know that different cron installs slightly differ from one another.  In fact, my mac's cron expressions differ from ones on linux too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These entries can't be combined because two fields differ.

If, for instance, only the 5th field varied, you could do

```
0 55 * * * 1,2,7 *
```

Comment: Yeah. I kind of assumed as much. Just wasn't sure. I kind of had the vague notion that any type of recurrence was supported, but I guess not.